# Experssion involving normal pdf and cdf

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm working on properties of truncated random normal variables. The following expression keeps on popping up in my results:
$$
\phi(x) \left[ \phi(x) - x \left[ 1 - \Phi(x) \right] \right],
$$
where $x$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$, $\phi(x)$ is the pdf, and $\Phi(x)$ is the cdf. I'm wondering if this is something someone has seen before. Visually, this is very similar (but not quite equal) to $0.56$ times the pdf of a normal distribution with mean $-0.86$ and variance $0.71$. However, I don't have an intuition why that is.

Does anyone know what this expression is? Or does anyone have any clues to understanding the intuition of this expression? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your $0.56$ may be closer to $0.56419$ as the integral of your expression over the real line.  Note that half comes from $\int \phi(x)^2\, dx$ and the other half from $\int -\phi(x)x(1-\Phi(x))\, dx$.  It looks to me like the expected value of the maximum of two independent standard normal random variables.  Your mean may be closer to $-0.886227 \approx \frac{1}{2 \times 0.56419}$

Comment: And your variance may be closer to $0.7146 \approx \frac32 - \left(\frac{1}{2 \times 0.56419}\right)^2$